# How to propagate a Kubernetes operator error to kubectl command line?

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk

I have a Kubernetes operator that creates a new Deployment based upon the custom resource configuration. There are some error conditions that will cause a failure and the Deployment creation step is skipped. Is it possible to have the error text displayed on the command line?

At the moment I have:

```
err := validateSettings()
if err != nil {
    // Log the error
    logger.Error(err, "The Deployment settings are invalid")

    // I also record the event in the custom object
    r.recorder.Event(object, "Warning", "Failed", err.Error())

    return reconcile.Result{}, err
}
```

When a user creates the custom object, the deployment is not created but the command line says that the custom object was created successfully.

```
# kubectl apply -f myobject.yaml

test.com/my-object created
```

The logs for the operator show the error and the a describe of the custom object show the event. I was hoping to have the event text displayed after the kubectl apply command.

Comment: Does a [validating admission webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook) do what you need?  If you're building your controller with Kubebuilder, it looks like [it has at least some support for this](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/webhook-implementation.html).

Comment: I'll take a look. I am starting to think that in hindsight what I want to do may not make sense. The custom object does get created and thus the success. Its a separate process that then invokes the operator and the deployment creation. ie the command line is not linked to the deployment creation.